# It is possible to run a Exe file in RedHat

Tags: scripts, executable, perl, batch

I am new to linux. I run the batch file which will execute exe file in automated way. I need to do the same in linux. Kindly give me some idea how to use it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried installing wine (http://www.winehq.org/)? That allows you to run some windows applications.

Comment: This question is ambigious, do you want to run actual Windows Binaries (.exe) files, or are you asking how you would make a .bat style "script" to run a fixed set of linux programs?

Comment: Actual windows Binaries(.exe)files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this anyway, even though this is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as this is about another Linux distro. Really you ought to ask the question on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - you can use the same [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) account.

To run most exe files, you can use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/). You can install it in most `rpm` based systems with:

```
sudo yum list wine*
```

Then you can click on exe files, and open them with 'Wine Windows Program Loader'.

As for batch files, that is harder, but you may be able to use a Windows like terminal that comes with Wine - you can open that by running:

```
wineconsole
```

Comment: It is possible to use wine for automatic way?@wilf

Comment: `wine` will do just about anything you can do on Windows. However, more advanced software may require a bit of tweaking. Head to [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org) for more information.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info, stuck this in before it is flagged as closed. Wine should automatically open 'exe` files if you set it in 'Properties' > 'Open With...', but in terminal you need to prefix it with `wine` or `wine start /unix FILE `

Answer (score 1):

## Exe files can not be run in Linux

The exe fileformat is something that Microsoft has coined and is something that only natively works in their operating systems.

There are, however, plenty of tools for you to run files with the .exe fileformat and the most popular one right now would be **[WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/download)**.

## Wine

Wine enables you to run software that only natively works in Windows, but in Linux instead.

Wine is not something that is foolproof and probably wont support every itty bitty application that you need to run. So to be sure that the application you are trying to run is supported I suggest that you head on over to their **[AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/)**. This page contains a lot of useful information regarding applications supported by Wine as well as some common bugfixes to the current version of the software.